# how to stat file with non ascii characters

Tags: c, file-io, utf-8, character-encoding

For normal file path, I can use stat and get size of it. When the path contains non-ascii names like C:\temp\sमानकe\app.log, it does not work.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
      struct stat FileAttrib;

      if (stat(argv[1], &FileAttrib) < 0) {
            printf("File Error Message = %s\n", strerror(errno));
      }
      else
      {
           printf("File size %d\n",  FileAttrib.st_size);
      }
      return 0;
}
```

stat takes only char *. The path received from command prompt is not really coming a valid file.

[image]

Comment: If you're able to otherwise open the file, you could always use `fstat()` on the file descriptor.

Comment: My mingw terminal, neither my editors are allowing me to even enter such characters. ha ha :)

Comment: are you sure you hand over the filename properly encoded and escaped? test with "ls 'C:\temp\sमानकe\app.log'".

Comment: @  Pavan Manjunath : I used mintty. see the output.

Comment: Your `main` is declared to take ASCII arguments, so your non-ASCII command line is not even making it into `main` intact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using Windows, try using [GetShortPathNameW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the short path name (if it exists), and then pass the short name to `stat()`.

Comment: On my WinNT 6.3, the short path names would still contain non-ASCII chars if they're not too long for 8.3 format.

Comment: Ouch. Interesting. This is true for *some* of the NTFS volumes only. While works as expected for the others. Well, can't be considered reliable, anyway.